# Is this a horizontal asymptote?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following function: $f(x) = \frac{(x-2)^2}{(x^2-1)}$.
To calculate the horizontal asymptote, we take the limit:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}} f(x) = 1$

However, $f(x)$ still intersects with $y = 1$, namely at the point $(1.25;1)$.

So is $y = 1$ the horizontal asymptote? Because it still intersects with $y = 1$, but the function approaches 1 as x approaches to infinity.

Comment: $y=1$ is horizontal asymptote, you got it right. Consider function $y=\sin \frac{1}{x}$, it has infinitely many intersections with $y=0$ which is  horizontal asymptote

Comment: Ah, that's really interesting. Thanks for the example! I assume vertical asymptotes can't be intersected, but horizontal asymptotes can right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. Horizontal asymptotes are happy to be intersected as many times as you like.

Comment: Oh alright, I thought horizontal asymptotes are never intersected, so the two contradicting results confused me. I've learned that horizontal asymptotes are values of y which the function approaches, but will never intersect, so that lead to the confusion.